# print non common elements from two arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to print the non common elements between two arrays. For example,
if `array1 = { 1, 3, 5}` and `array2 = {1, 2, 4, 5}`, my output should be `{2, 3, 4}`.

I have tried something here. But it prints only 3.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5 };
    int b[] = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
        bool contains = false;
        int result[10];
        int r = 0;
        int x;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!contains) {
            result[r]=a[i];
            ++r;
        }
        else{
            contains = false;
        }
    }
    for (x = 0; x < r; x++)
    {
        cout<< result[x]<<"\n";
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are the values from the two arrays sorted?  Or can they be sorted?

Comment: I recommend to use `std::vector`, `std::sort` and `std::set_difference`.

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman Whenever you have a task in hand that sounds "algorithmic", or sounds like "this has been written millions of times before by people out there", you should be looking for an algorithm functions or series of algorithm functions to solve the issue.  Getting common (or uncommon) elements between two sorted ranges is well covered by `std::set_difference` and `std::set_symmetric_difference`.

Comment: I know this is too old fashioned, but im more of a java person. I solved it easily using array lists.... I was trying to understand the c++14 features. Vector was one of them and I didn't know the set difference and symettric difference featurea. Thank you @PaulMckenzie

Comment: The standard library algorithms are not just syntactic sugar. They are highly effective, and they make the code shorter and less error-prone. In many cases they can replace, e.g., clumsy loops and if/else statements.

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman *I solved it easily using array lists.*  -- Yes, but if I were to look at your solution at first glance (and were not told what problem you were trying to solve), I would have to decipher all of those loops and if-else statements to see "ok, he is trying to find the uncommon elements". However, if I (and other C++ programmers) were to take a look at code that calls `set_difference`, we know immediately what is being done.  Not only that, algorithms **never** fail if the right function is called and is given the correct input parameters, thus no debugging is necessary.

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman: What does being a "Java person" have to do with that? You are not supposed to re-implement algorithms in Java using `ArrayList`, either; good Java style dictates using the static methods of the `Collections` class, which has an underlying philosophy very similar to the C++ separation into containers and algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

You did not add the unique values from `b` to `result`. But this is c++. I recommend to use `std::vector`, `std::sort`, `std::set_symmetric_difference` and `std::back_inserter`.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::set_symmetric_difference, std::sort
#include <iterator>     // std::back_inserter
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main()
{
    std::vector< int > a = { 1, 3, 5 };
    std::vector< int > b = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };

    std::sort( a.begin(), a.end() );
    std::sort( b.begin(), b.end() );

    std::vector< int > result;
    std::set_symmetric_difference( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(result) );

    for ( int x : result )
        std::cout << x << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/3jyy86)

As suggested by @ChristianHackl in the comment below, it is also possible to use arrays for `a` and `b` and using the free-standing functions `std::begin` and `std::end`:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::set_symmetric_difference, std::sort
#include <iterator>     // std::back_inserter
#include <vector>       // std::vector, std::begin, std::end

int main()
{
    int a[]{ 1, 3, 5 };
    int b[]{ 1, 2, 4, 5 };

    std::sort( std::begin(a), std::end(a) );
    std::sort( std::begin(b), std::end(b) );

    std::vector< int > result;
    std::set_symmetric_difference( std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::back_inserter(result) );

    for ( int x : result )
        std::cout << x << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's C++ like it should be, +1 from me. Perhaps the example could be further improved by retaining arrays for `a` and `b` and using free-standing `std::begin` and `std::end` functions,

Answer (score 3):

You added all the "unique" values from `a` to the `result` but you forgot to add all the values from `b` to the `result`.

**EDIT**

Something like that:

```
for (int i=0; i < sizeof(b)/sizeof(int); ++i, ++r)
{
    result[r] = b[i];
}
```

Comment: Is there a flag or something which I need to use to keep track of those elements?

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman no. after the double `for` loop that you already have you know that `result` contains only the values from `a` which are not in `b`, so jusst add all the values which are in `b` to `result`

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithmics is wrong here. For one thing your code runs in o(a*b) where a and b are the list lengths.

Besides, it only produces elements that are in A but not in B.

The way to do this is to sort both lists, then browse through A and B, moving to the smallest current element and adding it to the result if both current elements are different.
This will run in o(log a + log b + a + b).